# @POST array with retrofit

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I need help with sending @POST request. Right now my post method looks like this :

```
@FormUrlEncoded

    @POST("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/try-save-settings")
    void trySaveBeaconParams(@Field("beacon_id") long beaconId,
                             @Field("password") String password,
                             @Field("ib[turn_on]") int turn_on,
                             @Field("ib[minor]") int minor ,
                             @Field("ib[major]") int major ,
                             @Field("ib[tx_power]") int tx_power ,
                             @Field("ib[interval]") int interval,
                             @Field("ib[secure_uuid]") int secure_uuid,
                             @Field("euid[turn_on]") int euid_turn_on,
                             @Field("euid[interval]") int euid_interval,
                             @Field("euid[tx_power]") int euid_tx_power,
                             @Field("euid[namespace]") String euid_namespace,
                             @Field("euid[instance]") String euid_instance,
                             @Field("eeid[turn_on]") int eeid_turn_on,
                             @Field("eeid[interval]") int eeid_interval,
                             @Field("eeid[tx_power]") int eeid_tx_power,
                             @Field("eurl[turn_on]") int eurl_turn_on,
                             @Field("eurl[interval]") int eurl_interval,
                             @Field("eurl[tx_power]") int eurl_tx_power,
                             @Field("eurl[url]") String eurl_url,
                             @Field("etlm[turn_on]") int etlm_turn_on,
                             @Field("etlm[interval]") int etlm_interval,
                             @Field("etlm[tx_power]") int etlm_tx_power,
                             @Field ("sleep_modes[]") List<SleepMode> model,
                             Callback<BasicResponse<Object>> callback);
```

The problem is with array sleep_mode. When I send it as I wrote I'm sending data like this : [image: RESPONSE_UNCORRECT]

While I need to send in format like that :

[image]

I tried to do it with @Body but it hasn't worked then. ANy help please ? Thanks in advance.
My SleepMode.class :

```
@Table(name = "SleepMode")
public class SleepMode {

    @Column
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("turn_on")
    public int turn_on;
    @Column
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("time_from")
    public String time_from;
    @Column
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("time_to")
    public String time_to;
```

--------------------------- EDIT , VERSION WITH "@BODY"-------------------------

```
@POST("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/try-save-settings")
    void trySaveBeaconParams(
            @Body EonBeaconModel model,

            Callback<BasicResponse<Object>> callback);
```

EonBeacon.class

```
@Table(name = "eonBeacon")
public class EonBeaconModel extends Model {
    @Column(unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE, index = true)
    public long beacon_id;
    @Column
    public long bridge_id;
    @Column
    public long mesh_id;
    @Column
    public String name;
    @Column
    public String location;
    @Column
    public String mac_address;
    @Column
    public String firmware;
    @Column
    public String pcb_revision;
    @Column
    public int battery_level;
    @Column
    public String password;
    @Column
    public String assigned_bridge_id;

    @Column(name="Eeid")
    public Eeid eeid;
    @Column(name="Etlm")
    public Etlm etlm;
    @Column
    public Euid euid;
    @Column(name="Eurl")
    public Eurl eurl;
    @Column(name="Ib")
    public IbModel ibBeaconModel;
    @Column
    public String jsonIB;
    @Column
    public String jsonEeid;
    @Column
    public String jsonEtlm;
    @Column
    public String jsonEuid;
    @Column
    public String jsonEurl;
    @Column
    public boolean isBeacon;
    @Column(name="sleep_modes")
    public List<SleepMode> sleep_modes;
    @Column
    public String jsonSleep;
```

This is how i create callback :

```
@Subscribe
    public void validateNewBeaconData(ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand command) {
        Callback<BasicResponse<Object>> callback = new Callback<BasicResponse<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(BasicResponse<Object> basicResponse, Response response) {
                if (ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.statusCode == basicResponse.status) {
                    EventBus.post(new BeaconsSettingsValidatedEvent());
                    Log.e(TAG, "success: ");
                }
                else {
                    EventBus.post(new NetworkFailureEvent(ResponseStatus.getByStatus(basicResponse.status), basicResponse.status_msg));
                    Log.e(TAG, "failure validate: " );

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                EventBus.post(new NetworkFailureEvent(ResponseStatus.NETWORK_ERROR, messageString));
                Log.e(TAG, "failure: " + error.getCause() );

            }
        };
        service.trySaveBeaconParams(command.model
                ,
             callback);


    }
```

Validate class :

```
public class ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand extends ApiCommand {
   public EonBeaconModel model;


    public ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand(EonBeaconModel model) {

       this.model=model;
    }
}
```

and this is how I create a request :

EventBus.post(new ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand(beaconModel));

THANKS and sorry for so much code :)

Comment: post your sleepmode class too

Comment: @Nas I added it to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instead of Field use FieldMap

@FieldMap Map<String, String> model;

put your data with your key("sleep_mode[0]") in map
```

Comment: you mean :         @FieldMap List<Map<String, String>> model, ?

Comment: @FieldMap parameter type must be Map  <-- can't send List of Maps

Comment: then @Field ("sleep_modes[]") List<Map<String, String>> model will work for you

Comment: Done with : @FieldMap Map<String,String> fields,  and then : Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            SleepMode mode1 = new SleepMode("13:00", "14:00", "1");
            fields.put("sleep_mode[" + i + "][turn_on]", mode1.turn_on);
            fields.put("sleep_mode[" + i + "][time_from]", mode1.time_from);
            fields.put("sleep_mode[" + i + "][time_to]", mode1.time_from);

Comment: Yes it does:) Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130701/discussion-between-nas-and-bartos).

Answer (score 1):

You should try @Body annotation with something like that

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/try-save-settings")
void trySaveBeaconParams(@Body BodyRequest request);
```

And create a BodyRequest class with all your arguments :

```
class BodyRequest {
  long beaconId;
  String password;
  // ....
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggest but right now app doesn't send anything to API ;/ I can edit my post if you like.

Comment: I eddited the post :)

Comment: And you still have @FormUrlEncoded on your method ?

Comment: No I don't. I had  to delete it cause it caused an exception

Comment: Which exception ?

Comment: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding

Comment: Right now : Only one encoding annotation is allowed - with FormUrlEncoded

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/try-save-settings")
void trySaveBeaconParams(@Body HashMap<String, Object> map);
```

and then you can put anything as value of in that map

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("beacon_id" ,beaconId);
map.put("beacon_id" ,beaconId);
map.put("password" , password);
map.put("ib[turn_on]" , turn_on);
map.put("ib[minor]" , minor);
map.put("ib[major]" , major);
```

you can even add the list or array inside that map

Comment: thanks for help but when I create map , add fields to it as you suggest server returns null at every field. Nothing is being sent :/

Comment: in void trySaveBeaconParams(@Body HashMap<String, Object> map); instead of "Body" try using "FieldMap"

Comment: the same problem :/